# CSS to keep content in portrait or square mode

Tags: html, css

What would be the proper way to ensure that a webpage's square content is displayed "tall"? For example, if your phone or monitor is in portrait mode, then the content would take the full width, but if it's in landscape mode, then you'd get sidebars on the side of the content, so that the main body is a square, filling up the full height.

I've done this with JavaScript, by handling the resize event and checking the container's height and width, and manually calculating widths and margins. But I'm sure there's a better way, maybe even a pure CSS3 solution.

Looking at [Google's responsive guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/), I'm guessing maybe a custom stylesheet would do it, but I can't figure out how to always make the content always fill up either the height or width.

So here's what it would look like in portrait and landscape modes, where the red section is the main body, and the blue is extra filler space:

[image] [image]

I'm currently trying Angular Material, so if there's a solution specific to that framework, that would work too.

Here's what the layout would be inside the body - the Angular material grid tiles are each square, so the grid is 2x2 with 4 equally sized squares, meaning the full body would a square - and I want that 2x2 grid to be as big as possible without scrolling:

```
<body>
    <!-- if necessary -->
    <div id="left-side"></div>

    <div id="main-container">
        <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="1:1">
            <mat-grid-tile>First square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Second square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Third square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Fourth square</mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </div>

    <!-- if necessary -->
    <div id="right-side"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide some code and context. It might be that you're looking for object-fit but it's hard to tell without any actual code.

Comment: Is the red item variable in size or static?

Comment: @SvenvandeScheur Thanks, edited with a simple sample - a 2x2 grid with square elements, forming a big square, where I want the big square to be as big as possible without scrolling, regardless of orientation.

Comment: @staypuftman The red item is a square made up of equal-sized square tiles, but the actual size is dynamic - I want the tiles to grow and shrink so that they take up the entire width or height of the device/monitor.

Comment: Would you need the same rules to follow for tablet devices as well, or just for mobile? Reason I'm asking is difference in device widths. Would you need the portrait mode on tablet devices to display a full width square, or since it's closer in size to mobile landscape would the square have padding?

Comment: You can set the size of the elements in `vmin` units, e.g. `width: 100vmin; height: 100vmin;`. It would mean 100% of the viewport width in portrait mode and 100% of the viewport height in the landscape mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Content</div>
```

In portrait mode the wrapper will have 100% width, in landscape mode the wrapper width will be same as screen height.

For completeness, here is an example that matches the screenshots in OP:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
/* landscape mode: the wrapper is full height */
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
/* portrait mode: the wrapper is same height as width */
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #wrapper {
    min-height: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Content</div>
```

Comment: "vh" is exactly what I needed - that 100vh seems to be perfect. I suppose I need to study up on some CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the CSS grid defaults with the `vh` unit and get pretty close to this layout. Make a 2x2 grid, set the grid children to have a `50vh` height, center the grid container.

This works because `vh` will dynamically size to the height of the viewport automatically while `display:grid` takes over the horizontal positioning and makes the layout responsive automatically.

(Note: I put a `max-width` on the container and a tall `height` on `<main>` to show what's going on, but you don't necessarily need those).

HTML:

```
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
  height: 500vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/JZwvMQ

Comment: I had no idea that "vh" existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: blue;
}

mat\-grid\-list {
  display: grid;
  grid: repeat(2, 1fr)/repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background: red;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

mat\-grid\-tile {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="main-container">
        <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="1:1">
            <mat-grid-tile>First square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Second square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Third square</mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile>Fourth square</mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `aspect-ratio`, one can remove the media queries from @Salman A's answer. It was not widely available when the question was first asked, but now it has great support.

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: blue;
    }
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100vh;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">Content</div>
```